# Group Pandas DataFrame by multiple columns with connected IDs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe which contains several ids in various columns. Some of those IDs are missing or could be duplicated. The goal is to group the DataFrame by those ids and keep properties in a list.

To show an example that I would like to get:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'first_id': ['id_1', 'id_2', np.nan, 'id_3','id_2'],
        'second_id': ['aaa', np.nan, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'third_id': ['db_01', 'db_02', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'sources':[1,1,2,1,3]
        }
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

        first_id    second_id   third_id    sources
0   id_1    aaa db_01   1
1   id_2    NaN db_02   1
2   NaN aaa NaN 2
3   id_3    bbb NaN 1
4   id_2    ccc NaN 3
```

My desired output is:

```
data = {'first_id': ['id_1', 'id_2','id_3'],
        'second_id': ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb'],
        'third_id': ['db_01', 'db_02', np.nan],
        'sources':[[1,2],[1,3],[1]]
        }

# Desired output
pd.DataFrame(data)

        first_id    second_id   third_id    sources
0   id_1    aaa db_01   [1, 2]
1   id_2    ccc db_02   [1, 3]
2   id_3    bbb NaN [1]
```

I put together following function which does some grouping on the ids:

```
def get_element_from_pandas(col):

    """
    Takes first element from list. Used for pandas columns
    """

    if col is np.nan or type(col) == float:
        return col
    else:
        if len(col) != 0:
            return col[0]
        else:
            return col


def group_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame, index_to_group: list, group_columns: list, keep_in_list: list):

    """ 
    Group pandas datframe
    """

    df = df.groupby(index_to_group, as_index=False)[group_columns].agg(lambda x: [*dict.fromkeys(x)])

    for col in group_columns:

        # remove nan from lists (faster that when its in agg function)
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if str(i) != "nan"])
        # replace empty by nan
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x) == 0 else x)

        if col not in keep_in_list:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(get_element_from_pandas)

    return df


group_dataframe(df, ['first_id'], ['second_id', 'third_id', 'sources'], ['sources'])

# output is this
        first_id    second_id   third_id    sources
0   id_1    aaa db_01   [1]
1   id_2    ccc db_02   [1, 3]
2   id_3    bbb NaN [1]
```

Using that 'group_dataframe' I was able to get the result I wanted, however I had to apply it multiple times on the ids step by step. I believe there will be some simpler solution, which I am still missing. Thank you.

Comment: can you explain the logic more? why is `2` added to `id_1` ?

Comment: Probably because `aaa` is the common key?

Comment: what if `aaa` appears with `id_2` ? @Corralien

Comment: I suppose it's not possible :-) else the problem has no solution! Except if the row can be common to several groups. In this latter case, nan acts as a wildcard.

Comment: @Umar.H the 2 appears because of the aaa common key (as Corralien mentioned). Just one clarification. First_id, second_id and third_id are always linked correctly. That means that:  'id_1' , 'aaa' , 'db_01' will always be in the same row. They can only be empty. For example ['nan' 'aaa' , 'db_01']. So the problem is basically about finding all id connections.

Comment: The goal is to group rows 0, 2 using second_id (aaa) and rows 1,4 using first_id (id_2) while keeping the sources in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
out = None
for col in [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('_id')]:
    if out is None:
        out = ( df.groupby(col).agg(list)
            .applymap(lambda x: 'NaN_SENTINEL' if x==[np.nan] else x) )
        for col2 in [col2 for col2 in out if col2.endswith('_id')]:
            out = out.explode(col2).dropna()
        out = ( out.rename(columns={'sources':f'sources_{col}'})
            .replace('NaN_SENTINEL', np.nan).reset_index() )
    else:
        out = ( out.join(df.groupby(col)['sources'].agg(list), col)
            .rename(columns={'sources':f'sources_{col}'}) )
tempCols = {x for x in out.columns if x.startswith('sources_') and x.endswith('_id')}
out['sources'] = ( out.apply(lambda row: list({item 
    for col in tempCols if type(row[col])==list for item in row[col]}), axis=1) )
out = out.drop(columns=list(tempCols))
```

Output:

```
  first_id second_id third_id sources
0     id_1       aaa    db_01  [1, 2]
1     id_2       ccc    db_02  [1, 3]
2     id_3       bbb      NaN     [1]
```